# Include jar files from maven repository to eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

How can I include jars from local maven repository into eclipse project? Actually, I need to include them into WebContent/WEB-INF/lib directory in eclipse web service project, if it makes any differencies.

Comment: Are you using a Maven plugin? Are you talking about running from within Eclipse?

Comment: Should already work then; what plugin? What issue are you actually having?

Answer (score 1):

Open your pom file and add a dependency like this.. suppose the jar you want to add from local repository is myfaces-10.jar
and if it is in the path .m2\repository\org\apache\myfaces\myfaces\10\myfaces-10.jar .. then add a dependency in your pom.xml like this..

```
<dependencies>
    .
    .
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces</artifactId>
        <version>10</version>
</dependency>
    .
    .
```

now the jar will be available in the classpath and you can use it in your project..

make sure your groupId matches the path like in my example...

hope it helps..